# Is there an autocommand event after buffer is deleted?

Tags: buffers, autocmd

`help BufDelete`

> *BufDelete* Before deleting a buffer from the buffer list.

This is close to, but not what I am looking for: *After* deleting a buffer.

Comment: Looks like XY problem. There should be no valid reason for "after".

Comment: There was a recent mailing list thread about this